# Convert black and white pictures into color images

Tags: image-processing, color, image, conversion

I have a digital image of an old black and white picture. Is it possible, using Mathematica, to convert this old picture into a black and white image? For example:

[image]
[image]

This transformation was done using Photoshop and a special neural filter. But is it also possible with Mathematica?

Comment: Let try `Colorize[image, ColorFunction -> "CoffeeTones"]` and play with options.

Comment: In the wolfram NN repository:

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ColorNet-Image-Colorization-Trained-on-ImageNet-Competition-Data/

Answer (score 6):

Note I did not write any of this code, `netevaluation` is taken directly from the Examples -> Evaluation Function of the "[ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition Data](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/ColorNet-Image-Colorization-Trained-on-ImageNet-Competition-Data/)" page on the Wolfram neural net repository:

```
netevaluation[img_Image] := 
 Image[Prepend[
   ArrayResample[
    NetModel[
      "ColorNet Image Colorization Trained on ImageNet Competition \
Data"][img], Prepend[Reverse@ImageDimensions@img, 2]], 
   ImageData[ColorSeparate[img, "L"]]], Interleaving -> False, 
  ColorSpace -> "LAB"]
```

It produces a colored image, although in this specific case it seems the photoshop output is more vividly colored compared to this output:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVZWNm.jpg"];
img = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];

colored = netevaluation[img];

ImageCollage[{img, colored}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]